# how to attach a selected observable to a newly added item?

Tags: javascript, html, css, knockout.js

I'm new to knockout. I already have this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wguhqn86/1/) in which it will:

1. Populate the left box as the lists of items
2. Once you select an item in the left box,  it will show the detailed item in the right box

It seems that I have it running correctly. But I want to add more to it.

1. Upon load, select the first foo with its displayed details
2. Once I click the `+ Add foo` link, it will add new foo and have it highlighted then the editor in the right box will appear then when I click `save` it will add it to the collection of foo.

Is this possbile?

Snippet below

```js
var data = [
  { id: 1, name: "foo1", is_active: true },
  { id: 2, name: "foo2", is_active: true },
  { id: 3, name: "foo3", is_active: true },
  { id: 4, name: "foo4", is_active: false },
];

var FooBar = function (selected) {
  this.id = ko.observable("");
  this.name = ko.observable("");
  this.is_active = ko.observable(true);
  this.status_text = ko.computed(function () {
    return this.is_active() === true ? "Active" : "Inactive";
  }, this);
  this.is_selected = ko.computed(function () {
    return selected() === this;
  }, this);
};

var vm = (function () {
  var foo_bars = ko.observableArray([]),
    selected_foo = ko.observable(),
    load = function () {
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        foo_bars.push(new FooBar(selected_foo)
          .name(data[i].name)
          .is_active(data[i].is_active)
          .id(data[i].id));
      }
    },
    select_foo = function (item) {
      selected_foo(item);
    },
    add_foo = function () {
      // I have tried this but ain't working at all. Please help
      // foo_bars.push(new FooBar(selected_foo));
    };

  return {
    foo_bars: foo_bars,
    load: load,
    selected_foo: selected_foo,
    select_foo: select_foo,
    add_foo: add_foo
  };
}());

vm.load();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```css
.box {
    float: left;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.selected {
    background-color: #ffa !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
    <a href="#" data-bind="click: add_foo">+ Add foo</a>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Status</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: foo_bars">
            <tr data-bind="click: $root.select_foo, css: { selected: is_selected }">
                <td><a href="#" data-bind="text: $data.name"></a></td>
                <td data-bind="text: $data.status_text"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="box" data-bind="with: selected_foo">
    Id: <span data-bind="text: id"></span><br />
    Name: <input type="text" data-bind="value: name" /><br />
    Status: <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: is_active"> <span data-bind="text: status_text"></span><br />
    <button>Save</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wguhqn86/4/

```
load = function () {
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        foo_bars.push(new FooBar(selected_foo)
              .name(data[i].name)
              .is_active(data[i].is_active)
              .id(data[i].id)
        );
    }
    selected_foo(foo_bars()[0]); // default select first foo
},


add_foo = function() {
    var count = foo_bars().length + 1;
    var newItem = new FooBar(selected_foo).name('')
                .is_active(true)
                .id(count)
    foo_bars.push(newItem);
    selected_foo(newItem);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The new object you are adding didn't have the name and id assigned, that is probably why it was not showing up. In addition to that, once the new object is added you will need to select it before it can show up as selected in the left panel. below is my code definition for your add method

```
add_foo = function() {
    var new_foo=new FooBar(selected_foo)
        .name("foo"+(foo_bars().length+1));
    select_foo(new_foo);
    foo_bars.push(new_foo);
};
```

and the complete working fiddle can be found here http://jsfiddle.net/euq48em4/1/

Comment: I see. So that's why. Noted on that one. How about this one? `Upon load, select the first foo with its displayed details` and is it possible to add a new foo with the default `name = ""` and `is_active=true` then let the user fill in the fields?